# Ubuntu 14.06.02 LTS Upgrade to 16.04 LTS because APT dependency

Tags: apt, upgrade, 16.04, lts

I have multiple 14.04.02 LTS versions on the computers that I manage.

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

if I run

```
apt-get update then upgrade
```

I've got this message when I issue a `do-release-upgrade`

```
The required dependency apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)` is not installed.
```

I tried to reinstall apt as well without any success coz I get informed 
Cannot update apt because cannot download.

What can I do?

Comment: You mean apt,  not apk right?

Comment: Of course, my mistake. I don't know why...

Comment: You wanted to upgrade to 16.04?

Comment: Probably yes, but still no solution! :(